# Display a large image in the web browser control - MS Access

Tags: image, vba, browser, web, resolution

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

When trying to display a large image (larger than 5000x5000) in an IE web browser control in MS Access 2010, the image is not displayed.

I am using VBA to both navigate and write content to the object's document. I've tested both methods and I'm getting the same result. Smaller images render with no issues.

LE
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub DisplayImg(bWrite As Boolean)

Dim sHTMLFilePath As String
Dim sImageFilePath As String
Dim sContent As String

sImageFilePath = "d:\img.png"
sHTMLFilePath = "d:\html.html"

sContent = "<html>"
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & "<head>"
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & "</head>"
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & "<style>"
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & GetCSS ' gets css from db
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & "</style>"
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & "<body>"
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & "<img class=" & Chr(34) & "img_wb" & Chr(34) & " src=" & Chr(34) & sImageFilePath & Chr(34) & ">"
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & "</body>"
sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & "</html>"

If bWrite = False Then ' navigate
    Call CreateNewTextFile(sHTMLFilePath, sContent) ' creates the html file
    Me.wb.navigate sHTMLFilePath
Else ' write
    Me.wb.Document.Clear
    Me.wb.Document.write sContent
    Me.wb.Document.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide the tested code?

Comment: I added the code to my initial question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can?
Otherwise, you can Re-pixel the image here: http://www.garyshood.com/imageconvert/

And I found this on GoDaddy help:
"NOTE: Images need to to be formatted as .jpg, .jpeg, .gif or .png files. Image uploads are limited to 30MB per file. While images as large as 5000 x 5000 pixels can be uploaded, images will not be displayed larger than 1920 x 1080 pixels."

Comment: I tested the same thing in visual studio 2012 and it works, but I guess in Access this is not possible because of the control's limitations. Does that make sense? Re-pixeling the image is not a solution. File size is not a problem - I can display images of 30mb in size at 4000x4000.

Comment: Repixeling is not a solution? Why?

Comment: The picture I want to display is actually a large technical drawing that goes into a final report that has to be printed to scale. Repixeling would affect the details in the drawing. The report is also HTML and very large - (A0 or larger in size) and is shown in the app as well, with the same issue (the drawing is not displayed in the body of the report). For now, I decided to open the report externally, using the default browser - this is the only way it works for now.